# How to update application using wlst

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

From the console If 1 were to update the application what 1 does is..
1. Click on deployments.
2. Selects the application name and clicks update option.
3. Here he may change:

```
i. Source Path
ii. Deployment Plan
```

Now in my application No Plan path is specified so to update the application I only change the source path. The application gets successfully updated.

I want to update the application using wlst command by giving the new source path.
Is it possible?

like

updateApplication('backoffice','path\to\the\ear\file')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I believe the command you are looking for is `redeploy`:

```
progress = redeploy('myAppName', appPath='new/path/to/file')
progress.getState()
```

If you run into errors, you may need to put the new ear file into the original location OR execute an undeploy first, then do a normal deploy.

Reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1024321

Another example:

http://zachxu.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-use-weblogic-wlst-to-redeploy.html

Comment: I need to change the source path compulsorily...
Redeploy command doesn't allow me to change the source path.
It throws the following exception...

<Mar 20, 2014 12:02:02 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149007> <New source location, 'C:\Installers\redeploy_installer\backoffice.ear', canno
t be deployed to configured application, 'backoffice'. The application source is at 'C:\Installers\redeploy_installer\bo1_ms_installation\boo5_
as\backoffice\backoffice.ear'. Changing the source location is not allowed for a previously attempted dep
loyment. Try deploying without specifying the source.>