# Methods to deploy application changes without affecting currently login users

Tags: java, weblogic, web-deployment

I would like to know if there is a way to perform Java web application deployment without bringing down the servers/kicking the existing user out of the system.

Example, during application deployment restart of application servers will cause user to lose their session.

is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: osgi *might* help, I'm not sure though about http sessions.

Comment: You can do a 'hot' redeploy with weblogic as well, which won't require restarting the servers. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379102/how-to-update-application-using-wlst/22387316#22387316